Ruby on rails 予期せぬ値が取得されて処理が失敗する
実現したいこと
現在Ruby on railsで宿泊予約アプリを作成しているものです。
実装したい内容としては

施設詳細画面にて「予約する」ボタンを押下
予約確認画面に遷移し「予約確定」ボタンを押下した際に予約が完了する

というものです。
分からないこと
現在施設詳細画面は引数として存在する施設の値が指定されるように実装したため表示できている(http://localhost:3000/rooms/1)のですが、
予約確認画面に遷移すると存在しない施設の値が引数に指定され「予約を確定」ボタンを押下しても存在しない施設IDが値として指定されるためエラーとなっている状態です。(http://localhost:3000/reservations/29)
reservation＿contrrollerに記載のconfirmメソッドで値を取得している認識なのですが、下記のcreateメソッドとなにか競合する部分があるのか、そもそも上記の存在しない組織IDはどこから渡されているのかなど調べているのですが原因がわからない状態です。
ChatGPTにエラーメッセージを入力して対応を調べたのですが存在しない施設のIDが引数に指定されているということまでしかわからず原因がわからない状態です。
何卒お力添えをいただけますと幸いです。
エラーメッセージ
NoMethodError in ReservationsController#confirm
undefined method `update' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #43):
41
42
43
44
45
46

予約確定処理
  def confirm
    if @reservation.update(confirmed: true)
      redirect_to reservations_path, notice: "予約が確定しました。"
    else
      flash[:alert] = "予約確定に失敗しました。"

Rails.root: /Users/sunao/reservation_manager

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/reservations_controller.rb:43:in `confirm'```

予約確定処理
  def confirm
    if @reservation.update(confirmed: true)
      redirect_to reservations_path, notice: "予約が確定しました。"
    else
      flash[:alert] = "予約確定に失敗しました。"
      render :confirmation, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

作成処理
    def create
      @room = Room.find(params[:room_id])
      @reservation = current_user.reservations.new(reservation_params)
      @reservation.room = @room
  
      if @reservation.save
        redirect_to @reservation, notice: "予約が確定しました。"
      else
        flash.now[:alert] = "予約に失敗しました。入力内容をご確認ください。"
        render :new
      end
    end


他のサイトでも同じ内容の投稿 をされているようですが、予め質問の本文にその旨を明示しておいてもらうとスムーズに回答が付きやすくなると思います。 / 参考: マルチポストとはなんですか？何か問題があるのでしょうか？

ご回答いただきありがとうございます。ご指摘を頂き大変恐縮です、こちら私の方で本文編集とさせていただきます。よろしければ引き続き何卒よろしくお願いいたします。
